# SP Admin unable to upload profile picture through CA area

Tags: user-profile, picture

Getting following error when trying to upload user picture through Central Admin > User Profile area. However, it does have latest CU. It works in the Dev farm but not production farm (apparently farms are not same then). I get the following error as soon as I click on "Choose Picture".

= = = error = = =

```
11/26/2012 13:13:05.41  w3wp.exe (0x0F9C)   0x0F34  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:http://SP2010CA01:2010/_layouts/SelectPicture2.aspx?Type=User&accountname=colgate%5Clalfish&ApplicationID=6a3b1168%2Dfe19%2D434b%2Db46b%2Dc8c4d50790f5&IsDlg=1)   abc73df8-3a86-4f73-852a-845beca08df3
11/26/2012 13:13:05.52  w3wp.exe (0x0F9C)   0x0F34  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/  abc73df8-3a86-4f73-852a-845beca08df3
11/26/2012 13:13:05.56  w3wp.exe (0x0F9C)   0x0F34  SharePoint Portal Server    Runtime 7pm5    High    Url Path: "/_layouts/SelectPicture2.aspx"   abc73df8-3a86-4f73-852a-845beca08df3
11/26/2012 13:13:05.56  w3wp.exe (0x0F9C)   0x0F34  SharePoint Portal Server    Runtime 7pma    Exception   Unhandled exception caught during execution of Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.PageBase::ErrorHandler(). Exception information: Exception information: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetRawPartitionID(SPServiceContext serviceContext)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean ignorePrivacy)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean IgnoreUserPrivacy, Boolean backwardCompatible)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.LoadPictureLibrary()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.<OnLoad>b__0()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.OnLoad(EventArgs ea)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetRawPartitionID(SPServiceContext serviceContext)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean ignorePrivacy)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean IgnoreUserPrivacy, Boolean backwardCompatible)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.LoadPictureLibrary()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.<OnLoad>b__0()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.OnLoad(EventArgs ea)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  abc73df8-3a86-4f73-852a-845beca08df3
11/26/2012 13:13:05.56  w3wp.exe (0x0F9C)   0x0F34  SharePoint Server   Unified Logging Service c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: SharePoint Server 2010, ULSException14, 06d8f9f3 "sharepoint portal server", 0e00178d "14.0.6029.0", b2be5063 "microsoft.office.server.userprofiles", 0e0017e8 "14.0.6120.0", 4f7bb5a6 "tue apr 03 21:44:54 2012", 00000eac "00000eac", 00000039 "00000039", a20cc50c "userprofileapplicationnotavailableexception", 37706d61 "7pma"  abc73df8-3a86-4f73-852a-845beca08df3
11/26/2012 13:13:05.56  w3wp.exe (0x0F9C)   0x0F34  SharePoint Foundation   Runtime tkau    Unexpected  Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application available to service the request. Contact your farm administrator.    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.GetRawPartitionID(SPServiceContext serviceContext)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean ignorePrivacy)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, Boolean IgnoreUserPrivacy, Boolean backwardCompatible)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager..ctor()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.LoadPictureLibrary()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.<OnLoad>b__0()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.OnLoad(EventArgs ea)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  abc73df8-3a86-4f73-852a-845beca08df3
11/26/2012 13:13:05.56  w3wp.exe (0x0F9C)   0x0F34  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://SP2010CA01:2010/_layouts/SelectPicture2.aspx?Type=User&accountname=COLGATE%5Clalfish&ApplicationID=6a3b1168%2Dfe19%2D434b%2Db46b%2Dc8c4d50790f5&IsDlg=1)). Execution Time=154.387778334956 abc73df8-3a86-4f73-852a-845beca08df3
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting your User Profile Service Application? CA -> Services on Farm -> Stop User Profile Service -> then Start.

Comment: No. but i can try.

Comment: Can you also provide the production farm build number?

Comment: I see all kinda numbers but this one stands out more 14.0.6120.5000